# Find a formula for a random vector

Tags: probability

So I'm given an assignment in probability and statistics that states the following:

In a McDonald's place in New York on average a number of λ customers arrive per day. Every client then orders a drink with a probability p independently from the other clients and independently from the number of clients that came before.

Let Y be the number of clients that came in one day and X be the number of clients who ordered a drink in that same day.

a) Find the Law of distribution for X, if its given that in one day 5 clients came (Y=5);

b) Find P{Y=n, X=k}

c) Find the law of distribution for X and E(X) if its unknown how many clients came in one day

For a) I assume the answer is that X has a binomial distribution of X~(5, p) and that't that. However I have no idea how to solve b) or c).

I can assume that Y has a Poisson distribution P(λ) but I have no idea how to solve the vector or solve E(X).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for (b): There are two ways to look at it. We can say that $n$ customers came and $k$ of those $n$ customers bought drinks, or that $k$ customers came and bought drinks and $n-k$ customers came and didn't by drinks. Both work.

More detail:

> In the first case, it's a Poisson distribution for the total number of customers, and a binomial distribution for how many of them buy drinks. In the second case, it's two independent Poisson distributions (with new rates, possibly different from each other) for how many bought drinks and how many didn't. The final probability, in either case, will be a product of two probabilities.

Hint for (c): What's the rate of customers that buy drinks?

More detail:

> Yup, another Poisson distribution. We don't need to know how many total customers there are; the ones that didn't buy drinks don't affect anything later. So then, a probability $p$ of buying a drink multiplies the rate by $p$.

Comment: OK got it! So for b) what is the formula for the vector? Is it the formula for the Poisson distribution multiplied by the formula of the binomial?

Comment: Yes. Standard conditional probability; P(A and B) = P(A) times P(B given A).